# what drivers do i need to install if i want to connect my java program (using Netbeans 8.0.2) to mysql 5.5?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

i am trying to connect my netbeans java program to mysql 5.5 using DATASOURCE objects, and before starting do i need to install any especial driver , or are they provided with Netbeans ?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: No, I think. you just have to provide mysql jdbc connector jar in your program classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need the MySQL JDBC driver. Just put the MySQL JDBC connector jar in the project's classpath.